# The term $v$ (velocity) in Coriolis force formula $F=-2m(\omega×v)$ is with respect to which frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, conventions, coriolis-effect

Velocity as observed from the inertial frame or the rotating frame?

Comment: Rotating frame. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force

Answer (score 2):

It’s in the corotating frame.

The easiest way to see this is to imagine motion out from the central axis, where you are still moving in the nonrotating coordinates with some internal speed $R~\omega$ but your surroundings are now moving with speed $(R+\delta R)\omega$ and thus in the corotating frame you appear to have picked up a velocity $-\delta R~\omega$. (Actually it is even slightly worse in that there is another such effect (it gets doubled) due to the fact that during this motion two frames came to disagree on what direction “forward” was.)

In the corotating frame your radial motion $v_R$ is perpendicular to $\vec\omega$ and integrating over time gives $$\int (F/m) dt = -2\omega~\int v_R ~ dt= -2\omega~\delta R.$$